# Is it possible to share a cookie between a domain and a subsubdomain

Tags: cookies, subdomain

I'm trying to share a cookie between www.example.com and admin.other.example.com
I've being able to make it work with other.example.com, but there's no way to access the sub-sub-domain

Edit: I handle subdomains by defining the cookie domain as .example.com (note the first dot)

Comment: Please share your so far findings with us. How do you manage to handle subdomains?

Answer (score 4):

You can only share cookies between a domain and its **own** subdomains.
For example:

- a cookie defined for the domain `example.com` can be accessed by `www.example.com` and `foo.bar.example.com`
- a cookie defined for the domain `www.example.com` can be accessed by `foo.www.example.com` but not by `bar.example.com`

Comment: to be more accurate, a cookie for `.example.com` can be accessed by its subdomains. notice the leading period

Comment: But how do I PREVENT `foo.example.com` from reading `example.com`'s cookies? I need the subdomain to be completely separate. I don't want `example.com` reading `foo.example.com`'s cookies either.